# HTTP 1.0 request with HTTPoison

Tags: elixir, http-1.0, httpoison

How do I make a HTTP/1.0 request with HTTPoison? I don't know which version it's using, but I'm assuming it's not 1.0 by default.

I am integrating with some accounting software called MoneyWorks, and they [recommend using HTTP/1.0 if possible to avoid a 2 second timeout delay](https://secure.cognito.co.nz/developer/moneyworks-datacentre-rest-api/).

I don't see anything in the HTTPoison docs for this so I went to the Hackney docs since it's built on that. Didn't see anything there either.

Answer (score 2):

In this case I would use [ibrowse](https://github.com/cmullaparthi/ibrowse), which - as Github documentation states - supports HTTP 1.0. Maybe better idea is start with [Httpotion](https://hex.pm/packages/httpotion), which is built on the ibrowse.

As you wrote, there is no info about supporting this version for Hackney (which means is also unknown for Httpoison).

Comment: This might work, thanks!. It looks like Httpotion lets you specify ibrowse options, and there's an ibrowse option for "http_vsn" so I'm assuming I can specify it there.